# What level will a non-imported character be at the end of the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What level should I expect to reach if I complete all optional content in the base game (no DLC) with a non-imported character (so starting at level 1)?  I want to make sure that I'm not setting myself up for skills that I won't be able to reach in this playthrough.

Comment: You'll be at least a few levels over 30, which is where I am, but I'm not at the end yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished at level 40 with a non-imported Shepard.

Comment: can you provide a bit more proof/info on how you got level 40.

Comment: Yeah I finished right around 40 as well

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to get past level 40 with a new character. On my playthrough I finished at level 45 with 3-4 skipped missions. That includes the "From Ashes" DLC but that's not that much exp (maybe an extra level or so).

Answer (score -1):

You can probably expect to be somewhere around level 35. I'll see if I can dig up any sources.